# Kubernetes connection refuses often

Tags: kubernetes, connection, kubeadm, kubectl, centos9

I have configured Kubernetes using kubeadm in cent os stream 9. When I issue kubectl commands i am getting this error often

> The connection to the server xx.xxx.xx.xx:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

I have used Flannel as CNI.

I have tried the `swapoff -a` command. And done `export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`
Restarting kubelet works sometimes but again gets the same error.

kube-api-server logs shows as follows,

```
2023-05-22T14:26:09.871029029+05:30 stderr F W0522 08:56:09.870881       1 storage_scheduling.go:106] unable to get PriorityClass system-node-critical: Get "https://[::1]:6443/apis/scheduling.k8s.io/v1/priorityclasses/system-node-critical": dial tcp [::1]:6443: connect: connection refused. Retrying...
2023-05-22T14:26:09.8710991+05:30 stderr F E0522 08:56:09.870905       1 storage_rbac.go:187] unable to initialize clusterroles: Get "https://[::1]:6443/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterroles": dial tcp [::1]:6443: connect: connection refused
2023-05-22T14:26:09.871143932+05:30 stderr F W0522 08:56:09.871088       1 storage_scheduling.go:106] unable to get PriorityClass system-node-critical: Get "https://[::1]:6443/apis/scheduling.k8s.io/v1/priorityclasses/system-node-critical": dial tcp [::1]:6443: connect: connection refused. Retrying...
2023-05-22T14:26:09.871221589+05:30 stderr F F0522 08:56:09.871144       1 hooks.go:203] PostStartHook "scheduling/bootstrap-system-priority-classes" failed: unable to add default system priority classes: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Please provide a solution. I have tried out most of the solutions from Google

Comment: `connection refused` indicates that the service you want to reach is not running. It makes sense that restarting it (or starting it) fixes that. Read the error logs to find out why it stops.

Comment: kube-api-server logs shows, storage_scheduling.go:106] unable to get PriorityClass system-node-critical:": dial tcp [::1]:6443: connect: connection refused. Retrying...
2023-05-22T14:17:52.882543812+05:30 stderr F F0522 08:47:52.882492       1 hooks.go:203] PostStartHook "scheduling/bootstrap-system-priority-classes" failed: unable to add default system priority classes: timed out waiting for the condition
stderr,storage_rbac.go:187] unable to initialize clusterroles: Get "https://[::1]:6443/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterroles": dial tcp [::1]:6443: connect: connection refused

Comment: Please edit your question to add additional information. It's unreadable in the comments.

Comment: I have edited the question